# Proof $e^x - 1 \le e x$ for $x \in [0, 1]$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

In reading a recent paper, I came across the inequality: $e^x - 1 \le e x$ for $x \in [0, 1]$.

I tried to prove this using (the reverse) Bernoulli's inequality i.e. $(1 + y)^r \le 1 + ry$, for $r \in [0, 1], y \in [-1, \infty)$, per [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality). Here using substitutions $y = e - 1 \ge -1$ and $r = x \in [0, 1]$.
This yielded:
\begin{align*}
(1 + (e - 1))^x &\le 1 + x(e - 1) \\
\implies e^x &\le ex + (1 - x) \\
\iff e^x - 1 &\le ex - x \\
\implies e^x - 1 &\le ex \quad \text{since $x \in [0, 1] \Leftrightarrow - x \in [-1, 0]$}
\end{align*}

2 questions: First, are there any issues with the above proof?
Second, can anyone suggest another way to prove this? There are
many such lemmas used in this paper, so thought to check.

Comment: Have you heard about the Lambert-W function before? I think it could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $x\in[0,1]$ we have: $$(1+ex-e^x)'=e-e^x\geq0$$
Thus, $$1+ex-e^x\geq1+e\cdot0-e^0=0.$$

You can use Bernoulli for the following.
$$(1+ex)^{\frac{1}{x}}\geq e$$ but to check before the original inequality for $x=0.$

Comment: Thanks! One silly question, how to rigorously justify the $e - e^x \ge 0$ for $x \in [0, 1]$? I know this statement is clear from a plot, but just want to make all these lemmas airtight using efficient proofs as I go through the work.

Comment: @user4687531   Because $e^x\leq e^1=e.$

Comment: Also, for my clarification, are there any gaps/issues in the proof I presented?

Comment: @user4687531  I think, Bernoulli does not work because $e-1<1$ is wrong ,

Comment: Ah, but here I'm using $(1+x)^{r} \geq 1+r x \quad$ for $x \geq-1, r \in \mathbb{R} \backslash(0,1) .$ Reverse for $r \in[0,1]$ i.e. the reverse Bernoulli, per this reference: https://www.lkozma.net/inequalities_cheat_sheet/ineq.pdf, so we just require $e - 1 \ge -1$ which is true here, correct?

Comment: @user4687531   I added something. See now.

Answer (score 2):

For $0\le x\le1$ we have

$$e^x-1=\int_0^xe^t\,dt\le\int_0^xe\,dt=ex$$

since $e^t$ is an increasing function of $t$ (and $x\le1$).

Comment: This is a very elegant solution!

Comment: I agree. Nice solution! +1

Comment: If I knew how to summon up emojis, I would insert the blush one here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof using mean value theorem. The inequality is trivial for $x=0$. For $0 < x \leq 1, $ define
$$f: [0,x] \to \Bbb{R}:  y \mapsto ey - e^y +1$$
Then $f'(y) = e-e^y \geq 0$ for all $y \in [0,x]\subseteq [0,1]$.  By the mean value theorem, there is $\xi\in (0,x)$ with

$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}= f'(\xi) \geq 0$$

But then $$0 \le\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}= \frac{ex-e^x+1}{x}$$
and thus $0 \leq ex-e^x+1 \iff  e^x-1 \leq ex$ as desired.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the alternative proof!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @user4687531 I recommend to try to understand my answer. While it may not be the most elegant, it is a technique that often works when proving simple inequalities involving differentiable functions.

Comment: Thanks @MathQED, I appreciate it. I'm familiar with the technique, but didn't jump to it here. Good to know. Is there anything wrong with the proof I've presented?

Comment: @user4687531 If the version of Bernouilli you quoted is correct, then your proof is correct as well.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

The perhaps most versatile inequality about the exponential is
$$\tag1 e^t\ge 1+t$$
for all $t\in \Bbb R$.
For $x\ge0$ we can apply $\int_0^x\mathrm dx$ to both sides and obtain
$$\tag2 e^x\ge 1+x+\frac12x^2.$$
From this,
Hence (at least for $0\le x\le 1$)
$$\begin{align} (1+\tfrac32x)e^{-x}&\ge (1+\tfrac32x)(1-x+\tfrac12x^2)\\
&=1+\frac12x-x^2+\frac34x^3\\&=1+\frac x4(2(1-x)^2+x^2)\\&\ge1.\end{align}$$
By multiplication with $e^x$ ($>0$) and rearranging,
$$e^x\le 1+\frac32x.$$
Your lemma then follows from $e>\frac32$.

Comment: Your derivation of (2) seems self-restricted to $x\ge0$, so how do you get from it to $e^{-x}\ge1-x+{1\over2}x^2$ (for $0\le x\le1$)?